# how can I pass my remove function with a parameter inside InpuTime?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I'm trying to pass a remove function into the map with a parameter, but it's like I'm not using my function. What would be the correct way to call ''remove(i)'' inside InputTime in onRemove?

```
Component
    
    render() {
    const {remove} = this.props;

    return(
      <>
          <InputTime
            onRemove={() => remove(i)}
            {...this.props}
          />
      </>
    )
  }
}

// another class
  handlerRemove(){
    ...
  }
return(
   <Component remove={() => this.handlerRemove()} />
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with a solution

```js
render() {
    const {remove} = this.props;


    return(
      <>
        
            <InputTime
              time={hour}
              onRemove={() => remove(i)}
              {...this.props}
            />
         
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

As you have done the destructing using `const {values, remove} = this.props;`, then you don't need to add `this` for prop function.

Current code `onRemove={() => this.remove(i)}`

Change you code to `onRemove={() => remove(i)}`

As the user change the code a bit, based on that the solution

```js
Component
    
    render() {
    const {remove} = this.props;
    const arg = "test";

    return(
      <>
          <InputTime
            onRemove={() => remove(arg)}
            {...this.props}
          />
      </>
    )
  }
}

// another class
  handlerRemove(passedArg){
    console.log("passedArg", passedArg);
  }
return(
   <Component remove={this.handlerRemove} />
)
```

Comment: interesting explanation, thank you. I've tried that way and it didn't work. I'm passing the function from a class to this class like this:
<Component onRemove={this.handleRemoveTime} />

Comment: @RenanFernandes add some changes, have a look

Comment: thanks but my problem is still not resolved. If my handleRemove function receives a parameter, how will I send it via onRemove? @Shiladitya